# Possible to host a parent and child domain on one bind server?

Tags: debian, dns, bind

*NB This is a repost of [my previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406417/one-bind-server-host-parent-and-two-child-dns-domains), which was put on hold, and asked to be reworded for better clarity (hope this makes more sense)*

---

I have a single DNS server with `bind` installed, which I am trying to setup to host a parent domain (`example.org`) and two sub domains (`cnc.example.org` and `report.example.org`) so that devices within any of the domains can have DNS queries serviced by the single DNS Server.

My first question is this possible ?

If so why would I do I receive the the following errors ?

When I do `nslookup host1` from the `report.example.org` domain I receive

```
server can't find host1: SERVFAIL
```

When I do `nslookup host2` from the `cnc.example.org` domain I receive

```
server can't find host1: SERVFAIL
```

[image: network topology]

Setup as follows:

host1:

- IP 192.168.252.21/24
- DNS 192.168.252.22
- `/etc/hosts` contains `host1.cnc.example.org`

host2:

- IP 192.168.252.20/24
- DNS 192.168.252.22
- `/etc/hosts` contains `host2.report.example.org`

DNSServer:

- IP 192.168.252.22/24
- DNS 127.0.0.1
- `/etc/hosts` contains `DNSServer.example.org`

**`named.conf.local` configuration**

```
/
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

zone "example.org" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/example.org";
#    allow-transfer { 192.168.252.22; };
};

zone "cnc.example.org" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/cnc.example.org";
#    allow-transfer { 192.168.252.22; };
};

zone "report.example.org" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/report.example.org";
#    allow-transfer { 192.168.252.22; };
};

zone "252.168.192.in-appr.arpa" {
     type master;
     file "/etc/bind/zones/reverse/rev.252.168.192";
     allow-transfer { 192.168.252.22; };
};
```

**`example.org` configuration**

```
;
; BIND data for example.org or report.example.org
;
$TTL 3h
@           IN  SOA DNSServer.example.org.  root.example.org. (
                        1       ; serial
                        3h      ; refresh
                        1h      ; retry
                        1w      ; expire
                        1h )    ; minimum
;
; main domain name servers - NS records
                    IN  NS  DNSServer.example.org.


; main domain name servers - A records
DNSServer               IN  A   192.168.252.22


;delegated zones
cnc.example.org.                IN  NS  DNSServer.example.org.
report.example.org.         IN  NS  DNSServer.example.org.
```

*** output from /etc/resolv.conf on DNSServer ***

```
  # Generated by NetworkManager
    search example.org
    nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

*** output from /etc/resolv.conf on host1 ***

```
 # Generated by NetworkManager
    search report.example.org
    nameserver 192.168.252.22
```

*** output from /etc/resolv.conf on host2 ***

```
  # Generated by NetworkManager
    search cnc.example.org
    nameserver 192.168.252.22
```

*** output from dig DNSServer on the DNSServer ***

```
root@DNSServer:/etc/bind/zones/reverse# dig DNSServer

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> DNSServer
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 45573
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;DNSServer.         IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Nov 27 10:47:23 GMT 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 38
```

*** output using dig DNSServer.example.org ***

```
   root@DNSServer:/home/osboxes# dig DNSServer.example.org

    ; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> DNSServer.example.org
    ;; global options: +cmd
    ;; Got answer:
    ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 12335
    ;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

    ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
    ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
    ;; QUESTION SECTION:
    ;DNSServer.example.org.     IN  A

    ;; ANSWER SECTION:
    DNSServer.example.org.  10800   IN  A   192.168.252.22

    ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
    example.org.        10800   IN  NS  DNSServer.example.org.

    ;; Query time: 0 msec
    ;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
    ;; WHEN: Mon Nov 27 11:01:19 GMT 2017
    ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 79
```

*** output from dig host1 on DNSServer ***

```
root@DNSServer:/etc/bind/zones/reverse# dig host1

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> host1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 19414
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;host1.         IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Nov 27 10:48:15 GMT 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 40
```

**`cnc.example.org` configuration**

```
;
; BIND data for example.org or report.example.org
;
$TTL 3h
@           IN  SOA DNSServer.example.org.  root.example.org. (
                        1       ; serial
                        3h      ; refresh
                        1h      ; retry
                        1w      ; expire
                        1h )    ; minimum
;
; main domain name servers - NS records
@                   IN  NS  DNSServer.example.org.


; main domain name servers - A records
;DNSServer              IN  A   192.168.252.22


;192.168.252.0/24 - A Records
host1.cnc.example.org.      IN  A   192.168.252.21
```

**`report.example.org` configuration**

```
;
; BIND data for example.org or report.example.org
;
$TTL 3h
@           IN  SOA DNSServer.example.org.  root.example.org. (
                        1       ; serial
                        3h      ; refresh
                        1h      ; retry
                        1w      ; expire
                        1h )    ; minimum
;
; main domain name servers - NS records
@                   IN  NS  DNSServer.example.org.

; main domain name servers - A records
DNSServer               IN  A   192.168.252.22

;192.168.252.0/24 - A Records
host2.report.example.org.   IN  A   192.168.252.20
```

thanks

Comment: roaima i did, but was also then asked not post images, so thought it easier to delete the question and start again, after I knew about the {} formatting

Comment: roaima I have deleted the older one.

Comment: @roaima i'd be happy with any configuration to be honest, this was just me first stab at configuring it. All i need is for new devices to be able to query two domains (cnc.exampe.org and report.example.org) so that when they want to dial back to the network, if they connet back for command and control messages they query dns and directed to host1.cnc.example.org and when they want to send repports back they query dns and are directed to host2.report.example.org - does that make sense ?

Comment: @roaima and @ Abhik Bose I made the suggested changes but I still get the same message. On the DNSServer when I do nslookup host1 I get:  `root@host1:/home/osbixes# nslookup host2
Server:      127.0.0.1
Address     127.0.0.1#53

** server can’t find host2: SERVFAIL`

Comment: from host1 or host2 I get `root@host1:/home/osbixes# nslookup host2
Server:      192.168.252.22
Address     192.168.252.22#53

** server can’t find host2: SERVFAIL`

Comment: I assume the /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname files on host1 and host2 should still be host1.cnc.example.org and host2.report.example.org

Comment: From either of the hosts when I do nslookup host1.cnc.example.org or nslookup host2.report.example.org it correctly resolves the IP address

Comment: If `DNS: 127.0.0.1` means the bind server listens only on loopback adress then it can not be reachable from other servers and this may explain part of your problems. Also, take the habit to use `dig` instead of `nslookup` and always specify the nameserver to use. Finally, if you get a SERVFAIL you may have more information in your logfiles as to what as happened (If the query reached the nameserver of course). You need to make sure to understand the difference between a recursive and an authoritative nameserver.

Comment: @roaima I have added the contents of /etc/resolv.conf for the three devices into the question thanks

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I have checked logs at /var/log/syslog and there are no errors. it says all zones loaded and running

Comment: @PatrickMevzek i have added output from dig DNSServer and dig host1 run on the DNSServer

Answer (score 2):

You can use delegation, but unless you really need it I would suggest that you keep things simple and use one zone that contains `example.org`, `cnc.example.org`, and `report.example.org`.

```
;
; BIND data for example.org
;
$TTL 3h
@           IN  SOA DNSServer.example.org.  root.example.org. (
                        1       ; serial
                        3h      ; refresh
                        1h      ; retry
                        1w      ; expire
                        1h )    ; minimum
;
; main domain name servers - NS records
                    IN  NS  DNSServer.example.org.

; main domain name servers - A records
DNSServer           IN  A  192.168.252.22

; public targets
cnc                 IN  CNAME  host1.cnc
report              IN  CNAME  host2.report

; hosts delivering services
host1.cnc           IN  A   192.168.252.21
host2.report        IN  A   192.168.252.20
```

---

Quoting from comments:

> On the DNSServer when I do `nslookup host1` I get
>
> ```
> root@host1:/home/osbixes# nslookup host2
> Server: 127.0.0.1
> Address 127.0.0.1#53
> ** server can’t find host2: SERVFAIL
> ```

There is no search path on DNSServer, but the domain is `example.org`, which means that all unqualified names must be in that domain. There is no `host2.example.org` so `nslookup` is correctly failing to return you an answer. In this case you would either need to replace the `domain example.org` in your `/etc/resolv.conf` with `search example.org report.example.org` or else look up `nslookup host2.report`.

> From host1 or host2 I get
>
> ```
> root@host1:/home/osbixes# nslookup host2
> Server: 192.168.252.22
> Address 192.168.252.22#53
> ** server can’t find host2: SERVFAIL
> ```

Same reason. Your domain (search path) in `/etc/resolv.conf` does not include the component that holds `host2` so `nslookup` can't see the unqualified name `host2` anywhere.

> I assume the `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` files on host1 and host2 should still be `host1.cnc.example.org` and `host2.report.example.org`

I've no real idea what you mean when you say that `/etc/hosts` should be `host1.cnc.example.org`. The `/etc/hosts` file is an alternative way of mapping between host names and IP addresses. If you've only got two or three hostname you might as well avoid the complexity of internal DNS and just put those entries in `/etc/hosts`. On the other hand if you have a reasonable number of hosts then DNS is a good centralised solution for a local network. (Bear in mind, though, that `nslookup` intentionally ignores `/etc/hosts`.)

> From either of the hosts when I do `nslookup host1.cnc.example.org` or `nslookup host2.report.example.org` it correctly resolves the IP address

Yes. You've provided a fully qualified name, which `nslookup` (and `bind`) can resolve corectly. This proves that either DNS is working well.

> I need a single DNS Server to handle any queries for `example.org` and `cnc.example.org` and `report.example.org` so that when a new device communicates back to the network to ask for new commands to execute, it queries `cnc.example.org` and is directed to `host1.cnc.example.org` (192.168.252.21) but when it wants to send reports back to the network it queries the `report.example.org` domain and is directed to `host2.report.example.org` (192.168.252.20)

To do this you would use a `CNAME` (alias) record in the DNS, so that a query for `report.example.org` is mapped to the host `host2.report.example.org`. Note that there's no technical reason in your question why `host2` shouldn't be called `host2.example.org`. `CNAME` records can point anywhere, not just to hosts in the current (sub)domain.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I am going to spin up a few VMs and try these suggestions and will report back ! thanks again ! Also not snooping but great charity you have !

Comment: @Bat answer updated to address some of your apparent confusion

Comment: I have responded to your last comments - really appreciate your help with this and you taking the time to reply !

Comment: @Bat not sure what else you're asking, apart from now you're using `dig` instead of `nslookup`. By default `dig` does NOT use the `search` and `domain` values in `/etc/resolv.conf`. Try `dig +search +noadditional ...` instead of just `dig ...`  to enable that function.

Comment: I edited your respone and included some questions in there.  I basically need a single DNS Server to handle any queries for example.org and cnc.example.org and report.example.org so that when a new device communicates back to the network to ask for new commands to execute, it queries cnc.example.org and is directed to host1.cnc.example.org (192.168.252.21) but when it wants to send reports back to the network it queries the report.example.org domain and is directed to host2.report.example.org (192.168.252.20)

Comment: @Bat that's a different scenario! I'll see what I can put together later today

Comment: perfect thanks again for taking th time to help !

Comment: You are now officially my best friend ! I think your suggested setup is going to do exactly what my lab setup requires ! for final clarification are you suggesting that host1 and host2 can actually be called host1.example.org and host2.example.org and that the setup would still function the same ?

Comment: @Bat as long as the CNAME records point to the target hostname, and that target hostname has an A record for the IP address you'll be good to go.

Comment: ok thanks @roaima and thanks again for all your help. Do you have a crypto wallet for donations ?

Comment: @Bat thank you for the consideration. I don't expect payment for anything I do here - I choose to answer because I can. However, I have updated my profile should you want to take another look.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**. But no need to create sperate configurtion for subdomain.

A `.` at end means a full domain name and without a `.` it means a subdomain of the original domain.

Add entry like this for `cnc.example.com` in `example.com` configuration only.

```
host1.cnc      IN  A   192.168.252.21
```

So, you need the following updates

1. Remove `cnc.example.org` and `report.example.com` from `named.conf.local`
2. Add all entries corresponding to the subdomain without a `.` at end in the parent domain's configuration. You can also mention them explicitly in parent's zone like

   ```
   host1.cnc.example.com.  IN A  192.168.252.21
   ```
3. Remove zone files corresponding to `cnc.example.com` and `report.example.com` and restart `BIND` server.

Comment: i knew that "." was important but didn't know what impact it had, thanks for clearing that up ! I am going to spin up a couple of VMs and give your suggestio a go ! will report back thanks for the swift help my friend !